# Select from many rows where is value or is another value based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

In a table like this:

```
id_fk   | valid | val
----------------------
1       | 0     | val1A
1       | 1     | val1B
2       | 0     | val2A
3       | 1     | val3A
3       | 0     | val3B
```

How dould I select those that are valid=1, or if a valid one does not exist for a id_fk then one that is valid=0?

Basically from this table

```
id_fk   | valid | val
----------------------
1       | 0     | val1A
1       | 1     | val1B
2       | 0     | val2A
3       | 1     | val3A
3       | 0     | val3B
```

I want to select these (distinct id_fk per row):

```
id_fk   | valid | val
----------------------
1       | 1     | val1B
2       | 0     | val2A
3       | 1     | val3A
```

Comment: How did you get to 3k+ rep without knowing to show what you tried?

Comment: @Dukeling When I do show and explain what I tried it often turns into a wall of text, also I don't like guiding answers into a certain direction

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as you describe it:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable a
WHERE valid = 1
OR NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM myTable b
    WHERE b.id_fk = a.id_fk
    AND b.valid = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your valid columns having 1 and 0 only :

```
select * from (SELECT *
FROM Table1 a order by id_fk asc , valid desc) abc
group by id_fk;
```

[***fiddle***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/093e4f/3)